# Automapper Complex Object

Tags: c#, automapper

New to auto mapper, so I have it mapping correctly and this works:

```
public class Client
{
public string Id { get; set; }
public string Name {get;set;}
public List<Transactions> Transactions{ get; set; } 
}

Public class Transactions
{
public string Id { get; set; }
public string Name{get;set;}
}

AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(client, model);
```

But now I have created a more complex (view)object like so:

```
public class Client
{
public string Id { get; set; }
public string Name {get;set;}
public List<Transactions> Transactions{ get; set; } 
}

Public class Transactions
{
public string Id { get; set; }
public string Name{get;set;}
public List<TransactionType> TransactionType{ get; set; } 
}
Public class TransactionType
{
 public string Id { get; set; }
public string Name {get;set;}
}
AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(client, model);
```

So the issue is when I get to transactionTypes automapper does not map this.
I get Exception: AutoMapper Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

```
Mapping types: TransactionType_2C08CB54C0C3A13374A03ADCB16E8CD7258880F22CB679B7C590FFAECDD6A517 -> List`1 System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.TransactionType2C08CB54C0C3A13374A03ADCB16E8CD7258880F22CB679B7C590FFAECDD6A517 -> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ViewModels.TransactionType, WebUI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
```

Any ideas how I fix this?

Comment: show us your map configuration. Or this is some sort of dynamic map ? (sorry I only remember the basics of automapper)

Comment: Can you add what your model class is as well as the types of client and model.